# How do I change a tag's inner HTML based on their order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, innerhtml

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm practicing with smaller projects.

What I want to do is change the inner HTML of a bunch of tags to the number in which they are in order.

Let me explain.

I want to go from this.

```
*Number <br>
*Number <br>
*Number
```

To This.

```
*1 <br>
*2 <br>
*3
```

Doing it purely from JavaScript.

This is what I have right now.

HTML

```
<p id="thisIsANumber">Number</p>

<p id="thisIsANumber">Number</p>

<p id="thisIsANumber">Number</p>

<button onclick="orderElements()">Order Elements</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function orderElements() {
  var reference = document.getElementById('thisIsANumber');
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    reference[i].innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

Comment: bad code => **id must be unique**

Comment: Your first example shows `<br />` (line-break) elements but your second example uses `<p>` (paragraph) elements. They're different things. Note that `<br />` is a self-closing element that does not have content whereas `<p>` does.

Comment: Also, when setting human-readable text content, you should use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`.

Comment: To explain Mister Jojo's comment further — Your `document.getElementById('thisIsANumber')` is only going to get _**one**_ element because an `id` must be unique within a page. If you plan to have multiple items that are of the same sort of thing what you want to use is a _**class**_  `class="thisIsANumber"`

Comment: Sorry Dai, I never meant for the <br> tags to show up. I was using them to display the points as a list since, by default, they were displayed on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can't have multiple things that use the same `id` — you should use a `class` instead.

For example, this says you have a paragraph, and this *kind* of paragraph is a "numbered-paragraph":

```html
<p class="numbered-paragraph">
```

Now you can select all of the paragraphs that have that class, loop over them and give each a number.

This example code is explicit so it's clear — there are many ways this could be shortened:

```js
document.getElementById('numberGenerator')
        .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.numbered-paragraph');
            let i = 1;
            for (p of paragraphs) {
                p.innerText = 'paragraph number ' + (i++);
            }
        });
```

```html
<p class="numbered-paragraph">Number</p>

<p class="numbered-paragraph">Number</p>

<p class="numbered-paragraph">Number</p>

<button id="numberGenerator">Order Elements</button>
```

Note I've also used [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with an anonymous function instead of an inline *onclick=* with a named function.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you used an `id` instead of `class`. The problem with this is that an `id` is used to identify one element, whereas a `class` can be used to identify several. If what you want is numbered paragraph elements, and not an ordered list, this should do the trick:

```js
function orderElements() {
  var reference = document.getElementsByClassName("thisIsANumber");
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    reference[i].innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="thisIsANumber">Number</p>

  <p class="thisIsANumber">Number</p>

  <p class="thisIsANumber">Number</p>

  <button onclick="orderElements()">Order Elements</button>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation and solution!